# Tango Asus Zenfone AR

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I developed an app base on tango using java api. The app is working without problems in the Tango development kit and Lenovo phab 2 pro. Since a couple of days I tried to run on the new Asus Zenfone AR but I am getting this error.

```
I/TangoClientLibLoader: basePath: /data/data/com.google.tango/libfiles/
E/TangoJNINative: ERROR! Unable to load libtango_client_api.so!

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.SetBinder(android.os.IBinder) (tried Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_SetBinder and Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_SetBinder__Landroid_os_IBinder_2)
                                                                   at com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.SetBinder(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango$2.onServiceConnected(Tango.java:329)
                                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1468)
                                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1496)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

By the way,I used the Java Hello Video Example and I got this issue, maybe is related to my problem.

Any help would be great.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the target SDK in android build settings as 23.

There are some internal dependencies in `libtango_client_api.so` that require the target sdk to be set to 23. I believe they are working on fixing this issue in the near future.

Comment: Great, it is resolving part of the issue, but I still getting the dialog saying that there is a problem with the native libs.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? You should make sure that your Asus is updated to the latest BSP.

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is only displayed in development mode, so try in release mode